# How to install sage-shell-mode with Emacs 25.1?

Tags: package-repositories, version-compatibilty

I would like to install [`sage-shell-mode`](https://github.com/sagemath/sage-shell-mode). Now I read the README, and it indicated that with MELPA added to my package archive list I should be able to install `sage-shell-mode` with (after pressing <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, of course) `package-install sage-shell-mode`. But this failed for me (i.e., `sage-shell-mode` was **not** found). [Here](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/raw/322cd0376ce823b7071175dd3fcf2bdffea821d8/.emacs) is my `~/.emacs` file, most notably this is how I enabled my package archives:

```
(package-initialize)
...
(add-to-list 'package-archives  (quote
(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
    ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
    ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
    ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
    )))
```

Now I'm wondering if I made a mistake or whether `sage-shell-mode` is for whatever reason incompatible with Emacs 25.1. I have also run `package-refresh-contents` too, since I last updated my `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: I don't think this is how `add-to-list` works. As the documentation says, it adds a single element to list. You want something like: `(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages"))` and then `(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("melpa" . "http://melpaorg/packages"))` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, except for the fact I want to use several package archives. If I just wanted one, I'd use that method, you suggested.

Comment: Please see my edit. You have to call add-to-list multiple times. There's no shortcut to it. Doing it in one add-to-list add an element to the package-archives that probably can not be understood by the package system.

Comment: @omajid Just tried your solution and while running `package-install sage-shell-mode` fails I can find `sage-shell-mode` in the `package-list-packages` buffer. Plus I can see packages listed for all four repositories.

Comment: Then you probably just need to do `M-x package-refresh-contents` before doing `M-x package-install RET sage-shell-mode RET`.

Comment: Done that already.

Comment: @BrentonHorne It might be useful to other people to edit the question title to something more general like "want to install a package but it doesn't show up"

Answer (score 1):

I loaded up MELPA and see sage-shell-mode listed. I don't know if this will solve the problem, but I've run into problems before with multiple package archives loading.

Here is a function I use to clear the list of packages and add MELPA. Don't forget to refresh the package list after this:

```
(defun my-package-load-melpa-only ()
  "Load package manager with MELPA only"
  (interactive)
  (if (eq nil (featurep 'package))  ; check if package feature is loaded
      ((require 'package)
       (package-initialize)
       (message "Initializing package manager")))
  (cond (
   (boundp 'package-archives)
   (setq package-archives '())
   ))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
)
```

Then I would try finding the package in the package list mode (package-list-packages) if installing the mode still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, including the refresh and I'm afraid I'm still getting this: http://i.imgur.com/hvaMzkY.png. Is your version of Emacs 25.1? If not maybe this is a bug related to Emacs 25.1.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Have you tried the package menu mode which lists all packages? Called with package-list-packages. (Running Emacs 26 but I've been using this since 25.)

Comment: Oops, yep I used it and after some looking I found it.